# What js code to add here to get smooth scrolling?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

please check the below JS code, and suggest me further addition or modification in javascript -

JS :

```
var $tabs = $('.tabs > div'), _currhash, $currTab;
$tabs.first().addClass("active");

function showTab() {
   if($currTab.length>0) {  
     $tabs.removeClass('active');
     $currTab.addClass('active');
   }
/* find the panels and 'unlink' the id to prevent page jump */
$tabs.each(function() {
   var _id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(this).attr('id',_id+'_tab');
   /* eg we have given the tab an id of 'tab1_tab' */
}); /* set up an anchor 'watch' for the panels */
function anchorWatch() {
  if(document.location.hash.length>0) {
    /* only run if 'hash' has changed */
    if(_currhash!==document.location.hash) {
       _currhash = document.location.hash; /* we only want to match the unlinked id's */
       $currTab = $(_currhash+'_tab');
       showTab();
   }
  }
} 
setInterval(anchorWatch,300);
```

jsfiddle not working  so please check html and css link - [readmore](http://ssconsultancyservices.com/test.html)

Comment: Hello punit, thanks for your reply buddy.  but it's not working,  can u test it by going to read more link, I have added entire js code in single html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `showTab()`

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
```

Comment: sorry buddy, but its not working